# UITableViewCell subclass with Auto Layout constraints incorrect height

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift2

I have a `UITableViewCell` subclass, which I setup the views all in code and than add `NSLayoutConstraints` to. Everything is working, except my `UITabbleViewCell` is not calculating its height correctly.

Here is the code of the `UITableViewCell`

```
override func updateConstraints() {
    setupThumbnailImages()

    super.updateConstraints()


}
func setupThumbnailImages() {

    var imageViewXOrigin : CGFloat = 5.0
    var imageViewYOrigin : CGFloat = 0.0

     for thumbnailUrl in self.thumbnailsUrlArray {

            let miniPictureView = UIImageView()
            miniPictureView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
            miniPictureView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
            miniPictureView.clipsToBounds = true
            miniPictureView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)


            miniPictureView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false



        if((imageViewXOrigin + 50) > frame.size.width){
            imageViewYOrigin += 50
            imageViewXOrigin = 5

        }

        contentView.addSubview(miniPictureView)
        contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: miniPictureView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1, constant: imageViewXOrigin))
        contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: miniPictureView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: imageViewYOrigin))
        contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: miniPictureView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 50))
        contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: miniPictureView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 50))

        let lastImage = thumbnailsUrlArray.last
        if (lastImage == thumbnailUrl){
            contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: miniPictureView, attribute: .Bottom, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: contentView, attribute: .Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        }

            imageViewXOrigin += 50

        }

    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: contentView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: imageViewYOrigin))
}
```

What happens is the `miniPictureView` displays as it should, however its displayed outside of the `UITableViewCell`'s `bounds` and the cell stays at a height of 44.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the cell to size itself based on its contents, make sure you set the following on your UITableView:

```
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 // Or any other estimate you want, just make sure to set this to some value
```

A couple more notes:

1. Your `miniPictureView` constraints should be added to `miniPictureView` itself, since they don't involve `contentView` or a sibling view
2. In order for self-sizing to work, you also have to have a complete chain of constraints from the top of the `contentView` to the bottom.  So you should add an equality constraint between the bottom of `miniPictureView` and `contentView` so there is a constraint that will actually push the bottom of the content view.
3. I suspect your last two lines aren't helping.  The `contentView`'s height should be established by its top and bottom edges being constrained to its contents.  And the autoresizing mask is used to scale the cell and its `contentView` together. If you set that to false, you should at least replace it with code that sets the cell's frame to be equal to the contentView frame AFTER the layout is calculated.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add, this I set already. All my other cells work fine. Just this one where I do things all in code.

Comment: @Tander updated my answer with some more suggestions

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll give each suggestion a try and report back

Comment: I've tried the first suggestion, yet I receive an crash with the following: "Unable to install constraint on view.  Does the constraint reference something from outside the subtree of the view?"

Comment: @Tander  That's a strange error.  One thing I just noticed is that the second attribute parameter should be `.NotAnAttribute`, since there is no layout attribute accessible on a nil `toItem`.  So something like this should work:  `miniPictureView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: miniPictureView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 50))`

Comment: You're right that does work. I was adding it incorrectly. The issue I have is adding the bottom constraint only to views that are at the bottom of the contentView. If I have a single row of UIImageViews it is now working perfectly. Thanks for the help. I'll try figure out the other issue as its not in the scope of this question